# Finding the half-life of a decaying element.

Tags: calculus

I've already attempted to solve this problem by calculating for the half life as

$t/900 = \ln(2) / \ln(100/66)$

To find part b of the question, my calculation brought me to find $t$ at

$t/900 = \ln(100/47)/(\ln(100/66))$

However, as you can see above, both of the answers seem to come out as incorrect. If anyone could help me get started on this problem in a different way, or tell me what I'm doing incorrectly, it would be greatly appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left( \frac{100-33}{100} \right)^{t/900} =  \frac 1 2
$$

$$
\frac t {900} = \frac {\log_2 \frac 1 2}{\log_2 \frac {67}{100}} = \frac{-1}{\log_2 \frac{67}{100}} = \frac 1 {\log_2 \frac{100}{67}}.
$$

(I used $2$ as the base of the logarithm only because it makes it easy to deal with the denominator: $\log_2\frac 1 2 = -1$.)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to compute the half life of the element.

An exponential decay process is described by  the following formula $$N=N_0\times e^{-kt}$$ Let us use $N_0=100$; so, after $900$ days $$100-33=100\times e^{-900k}$$ which makes $$k=\frac{1}{900} \log \left(\frac{100}{67}\right)$$ Now, for the second part $$47=100 \times e^{-kt}$$ $$t=\frac{\log \left(\frac{100}{47}\right)}{k}=\frac{900 \log \left(\frac{100}{47}\right)}{\log \left(\frac{100}{67}\right)}\approx 1696.78$$